# Looking for Severi varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, octonions, jordan-algebras

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, and let $\mathbb{O}$ be the Cayley algebra over $K$. Let 
$$
\mathfrak{J}_{3}=\{A\in\mathcal{M}_{3}(\mathbb{O}):A\text{ is Hermitian}\},
$$
that may be considered as a $K$-vector space of dimension $27$. We are going to denote $\mathbb{P}^{26}=\mathbb{P}(\mathfrak{J}_{3})$.

Given $A,B\in\mathfrak{J}_{3}$ we may define:
$$
A\circ B:=\frac{1}{2}(AB+BA),
$$
$$
A*B:=A\circ B-\frac{1}{2}(A\cdot tr(B)+B\cdot tr(A))+\frac{1}{2}(tr(A)tr(B)-tr(A\circ B)),
$$
$$
A\times A:=A\circ A-tr(A)\cdot A+\frac {1}{2}(tr(A\circ A)-tr(A)^{2})\cdot Id,
$$
$$
\det A:=\frac{1}{3}tr((A*A)\circ A).
$$
We say that $rk(A)=1$ if $A\times A= 0$. Then, I want to prove that
$$
X=\{[A]\in\mathbb{P}^{26}:rk (A)=1\},
$$
is an algebraic variety of dimension $16$ such that its secant variety is 
$$
SX=\{[A]\in\mathbb{P}^{26}:\det A=0\},
$$
and that $\dim SX=25$ (i.e. I want to prove that $X$ is the fourth Severi variety).

It is stated in the last parragraph of p.18 of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1904.pdf) text, but I haven't been able to find a sketch of the proof of this fact.

There is an alternative way via representation theory that is explained in Lazarsfeld's book on Zak's work or in Zak's '*Tangents and secants of algebraic varieties*', but I would like to know if it is not very hard to see it this way.

Comment: page 6, here : http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9412012.pdf  perhaps can be useful for you.

Comment: see also page 28, Proposition 3.4 here http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4076v2.pdf

Comment: It is very nice to see that someone is still working on such subjects. I thought Freudenthal was the last one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer:

Let $A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
\overline{b} & e & d \\
\overline{c} & \overline{d} & f \end{array} \right) $ be the generic hermitian matrix with octonionic coefficients. This means that $b,c,d$ can be written as $X_1.1 +X_2.i_1 + \cdots + X_8.i_7$, where the $X_p$ are abstract variables (which will take value in $K$) and $1,i_1, \cdots, i_7$ are basis of $\mathbb{O}$ over $K$.

The symbols $\overline{b}, \overline{c}, \overline{d}$ are the conjugate of $b,c,d$ and $a,e,f$ are self conjugate, that is they are of the form $X_1.1$, with $X_1$ a variable which will take value in the field $K$. Overall, you have $27$ abstract variables $X_1,\cdots X_{27}$ (which will take value in $K$) coming into the picture.

Now, if you compute de determinant of $A$ (using Sarrus rule for instance), you will find a cubic equation in $X_1, \cdots, X_{27}$ which involves only integer numbers (the purely octonionic numbers disappear, which is kind of extraordinary). This computation makes sense because of the pseudo-associativity of $\mathbb{O}$, you don't need it to be commutative or even associatif.

This equation is the equation of a cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{26}$ and it is irreducible. Now let $Z$ be the scheme cut out by the $2 \times 2$-minors of $A$. Again one finds that the minors are equations in $X_1, \cdots, X_{27}$ with only integers coefficients (again the purely octonionic coefficients vanish).

Each minor is a quadratic equation in $X_1, \cdots, X_{27}$ and it is easy to see that they correspond to the partial derivatives of the equation of $det A$ with respect to each variables $X_1, \cdots, X_{27}$. Hence, the scheme $Z$ is the singular locus of $det A = 0$.

The scheme $Z$ is smooth. Indeed, if it had a singular point, this point woud be a triple point of $det A =0$. Being a cubic hypersurface, $det A =0$ would then be a cone, which isn't the case (this is a bit more complicated to check).

Now, $Z$ being the singular locus of $det A=0$ and this hypersurface being cubic, Bezout's theorem insures that every line meeting two points of $Z$ will be included in $det A=0$. This proves that $S(Z) \subset \{ det A = 0 \}$, where $S(Z)$ is the secant variety of $Z$.

Now two things are left to prove :

_$\dim Z = 16$,

_ the secant variety $S(Z)$ is actually the whole hypersurface $det A =0$.

I don't remember a simple proof of the first fact. Let's admit it. Since $Z$ is smooth of dimension $16$ and included in $\mathbb{P}^{26}$, ZAK's theorem on tangency gurantees that the dimension of $S(Z)$ must be at least $25$. The hypersurface $det A = 0$ being irreducible, we have $S(Z) = \{det A = 0 \}$.

**EDIT** : There is a mistake in the description of the $2 \times 2$ minors. Three of them will indeed be quadartic equations over $K$ with integer coefficients. The other $3$ will have fully octonionic equations, each of them giving $8$ equations over $K$ with integer coeffcients. At the end, wet $27$ equations over $K$ with integer coefficients, corresponding indeed to the $27$ partial derivatives of the equation of $det A$.

Comment: Thank you, it helps a lot! I'll ask regarding another interpretation of this variety soon. Maybe it is easier to prove the smoothness and find the dimension of $Z$ in this other way.

Comment: By the way, according to your answer, there is no need to define the operations of matrices that I have defined in my question, right?

Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan Well it depends how much representation theory you want to do. The operation that you defined will be helpful if one wants to see that $\mathbb{P}^{26}$ is pre-homogeous for the action of $SL_3(\mathbb{O}) = E_6$ and that $Z$ and $S(Z)$ are the only non-trivial orbits.

But if you really want to avoid representation theory then I have the impression you don't really need the equations you gave.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more thing. I don't get to see how do we use  Zak's Theorem on tangencies to conclude $\dim S(Z)\geq 25$. And I would appreciate if you could tell me an idea why $V(\det A)$  is not a cone. Thank you!

Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan Zak's theorem on tangency implies a bound on the defect of a smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ embedded in $\mathbb{P}^m$. It's also called Zak's theorem on linear normaility. In the special case here, it implies that a smooth $16$-dimensional variety embedded in $\mathbb{P}^{25}$ cannot have a secant variety of dimension less than $25$.

Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan If $X$ is a hypersurface in projective space, then $X$ is a cone implies that the Hessian determinant of any equation defining $X$ vanishes. I haven't done this computation, but I am pretty sure that the Hessian determinant of $det A$ does not vanish.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand it. There is only one more thing I would like to know. Is there an easy way to see that $Z$ is irreducible?

Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan Since $Z$ is smooth, if it is not irreducible, then it means that $Z$ is not connected. But then write $Z = Z_1 \cup Z_2$, with $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be connected components of $Z$. It's easy to check that $S(Z_1)$ and $S(Z_2)$ are contains different irreducible components of $S(Z)$. Since $S(Z)$ is irreducible, this is impossible, $Z$ must be irreducible.

Comment: Why $S(Z_{1})$ and $S(Z_{2})$ are not in the same irreducible component of $S(Z)$? (Sorry if this is too easy, but I've been thinking on it for a while and I haven't been able to figure it out)

Comment: @SrinivasaGranujan You're right, this is wrong. Then I don't know how to prove that $Z$ is irreducible :=)